# Can i get any statistics of users visiting page increase due to adding a notification

Tags: pre-post-comparison

Can I get any statistics or plots on numbers of users visiting a website before and after adding a pop-up or notification on their website which regularly asks users for filling some details in profile etc. just like on LinkedIn.

Edit: I just want to know whether the number of users increase (due to reminding them often) or decrease (due to annoying notification every time user signs in) if I include them in my website and I want a proof for that to show it to my manager.